# Use a variable name as a parameter in a bash function

Tags: bash, function, variables, dialog

```
#!/bin/bash

function dialog_menu()
{

    $4="$(dialog --clear --backtitle "Archlinux Installer" --title "$1" --menu "$2" 10 60 5 $3 --output-fd 1)"

}

dialog_menu "Disk Selection" "Please, choose where to install Archlinux" "sda 50G sdb 30G" DISK_SELECTION

echo $DISK_SELECTION
```

Tried this code but it didn't work well. I want to pass the $4 as the newly created variable which will be named here DISK_SELECTION. I need to use a function as there is multiple area where I need this entire code.

Is it possible ?

Comment: You might want to use an associative array, and do `arr["$4"]=$(dialog...)` then `echo "${arr[DISK_SELECTION]}"`

Comment: Working like a charm. Thanks buddy !

Comment: You're welcome! I will post my comment as an answer, so this question won't be listed as "unanswered". I'll appreciate your "accept".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use an associative array, and do `arr["$4"]=$(dialog...)`, then:

```
printf '%s\n' "${arr[DISK_SELECTION]}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification